# How to identify button click from array of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 1 button in each row, on click of button tax shown in that row will be applied to the client and i need to show some indication to end user. I want to change the button css(color, txt ect.) on click for that purpose. Below is the code -

```
<table class="data report_table">       
                        <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="taxVO" items="${taxVo}" varStatus="item">
                        <tr class="${item.index % 2 == 0 ? 'odd gradeX' : 'even gradeC'}">                          
                            <td><c:out value="${taxVO.taxName}" /></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn-icon" value="Apply" id="applyTaxButton" onClick="applyTax('${taxVO.taxId}');"></input>
                            </td>   
                        </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and jquery i am using is -

```
function applyTax(taxIdValue)   {
    $('#taxId').val(taxIdValue);
    $(this).$('#applyTaxButton').css("background-color","yellow");
}
```

but i am getting error - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method '$'. Can someone please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).find('#applyTaxButton').css("background-color","yellow");`?

Comment: yes i tried, although there was no java script error but nothing happens on the button as well. No change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/nbrooks/2z5zN/)

HTML IDs should be unique, so you should ***not*** have the all buttons having the same ID. Use the class attribute for that purpose. However, to simply change the context of your selection, the correct syntax is:

```
$(selector, context);
```

A **better approach** is to remove the `onclick` attribute altogether, and handle the event completely in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('.report_table').on('click', '.btn-icon', function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $('.btn-icon').not(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
    });
});​
```

Comment: Not working, no error but no change either, i think my JSTL loop is generating more tha 1 button and actual HTML is - <input onclick="applyTax('2');" id="applyTaxButton" value="Apply" class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey" type="button">, this might cause the jquery hard to find exect button

Comment: even though i made it dynamic(id) by adding loop counter value with button id, still it doesn;t work :(

Comment: Removing onClick() also doesn't help. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="taxId" type="text" /><br />

<input onclick="applyTax(this, '1');" value="Apply" class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey" type="button" />
<input onclick="applyTax(this, '2');" value="Apply" class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey" type="button" />
<input onclick="applyTax(this, '3');" value="Apply" class="btn-icon btn-small btn-grey" type="button" />


<script>
function applyTax(btn, taxIdValue)   {
    $('#taxId').val(taxIdValue);
    $(btn).css("background-color","yellow");
}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NFGkj/

But it's better to use jquery event binding.

Comment: You solution has 1 issue, i have to undone yellow once another apply button is clicked. only 1 can be of yellow color out of array of apply buttons

Comment: @Sachin I just show idea, for one yellow button try this: http://jsfiddle.net/NFGkj/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/NFGkj/2/